# Sequence ratio test.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The ratio test for sequences states that if $a_n$ is non-negative and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L$$

then $\lim a_n = 0$ if $L <1$ and $\lim a_n = \infty$ if $L >1$.

The test is inconclusive if $L = 1$.

Suppose $L = 1$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1) = 0. $$

Then can we conclude that $\lim a_n$ exists and is finite.

What are the most general conditions that guarantee the limit is finite in the $L =1$ case? For example, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$ and

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1 + O(f(n)),$$

then how must $f$ behave to guarantee that $a_n \to a < \infty$.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  What are your assumptions and what do you want to prove?

Comment: If $L = 1$, the inconclusive case, can we show that $\lim a_n = a$ exists with $a$ finite if we know $a_{n+1}/a_n = 1 +O(1/n^2)$ for example.

Comment: Is a finite limit guaranteed?  No, consider $a_n=n!$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of your questions:

If $a_n=\ln(n)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)=0$, but $a_n\to\infty$